# What impact on raising CloseSpider in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scraper

I want to know what impact of raising CloseSpider. In documentation http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#closespider there is no information about it. As you know scrapy process a few requests at the same time. What if this exception will be raised before last request will be handled? Will it wait for handling of rest requests that was prduced before? 
Example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    my_url = 'http://someurl.com/item/'
    for i in range(1, 100):
         my_url += str(i)
         if i == 50:
             raise CloseSpider('')
         else:
             yield Request(url=my_url, callback=self.my_handler)

def my_handler(self, response):
     # handler
```

Thanks for your responses.

========================
Possible solution:

```
is_alive = True

def parse(self, response):
    my_url = 'http://url.com/item/'
    for i in range(1, 100):
        if not is_alive:
            break
        my_url += str(i)
        yield Request(url=my_url, callback=self.my_handler)

def my_handler(self, response):
    if (response do not contains new item):
        is_alive = False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/342cb622f1ea93268477da557099010bbd72529a/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L148), if there is a `CloseSpider` exception being raised, `engine.close_spider()` method would be executed:

```
def handle_spider_error(self, _failure, request, response, spider):
    exc = _failure.value
    if isinstance(exc, CloseSpider):
        self.crawler.engine.close_spider(spider, exc.reason or 'cancelled')
        return
```

[`engine.close_spider()`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/342cb622f1ea93268477da557099010bbd72529a/scrapy/core/engine.py#L261) itself would close the spider and *clear all outstanding requests*:

```
def close_spider(self, spider, reason='cancelled'):
    """Close (cancel) spider and clear all its outstanding requests"""

    slot = self.slot
    if slot.closing:
        return slot.closing
    logger.info("Closing spider (%(reason)s)",
                {'reason': reason},
                extra={'spider': spider})

    dfd = slot.close()

    # ...
```

It would also schedule `close_spider()` calls for different components of Scrapy's architecture: downloader, scraper, scheduler etc.

Comment: thanks for answer. Maybe you know: how can I close spider and wait all requests that was called before I stopped spider?

Comment: @OleksandrHubachov I think it would still finish all requests "in process", I think the [`Slot` class](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/342cb622f1ea93268477da557099010bbd72529a/scrapy/core/engine.py#L24-L50) is responsible for managing what to process and what not. Hope that clears things up. Could you please describe what use case you've got and what behavior you want to change? Thanks, good question!

Comment: I have site with items. Url like in my question. And I don't know exactly what amount of items on site. I want to parse all of them. And when I will get an empty page I want to stop spider. And its important to receive all called requests before this magical moment. That is my problem

Comment: @OleksandrHubachov interesting. I think you can safely throw `CloseSpider` once you hit an an empty page. Test it.

Comment: thanks man. I edited my post with possible solution. I will try both ways and will update my post with right solution